# Compare two date fields using Parsley JS

Tags: javascript, validation, parsley.js

How can I compare two date fields using Parsley JS?

How can get the start date, while changing the end-date dynamically?

```
<input type="text" id="start-date"/>
<input type="text" id="end-date"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsley.js date validation in v2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969985/parsley-js-date-validation-in-v2-x)

Comment: It is not a duplicate... That Post is for single date validation. and this post for comparing two date.

Comment: It can be easily done using plain JS. Are you open to doing that?

Comment: @NisargShah : i know it is easy to write in plain js. i need to extend parsley validator.. that is my question. Raise up the vote, don't put unnecessarily

Answer (score 0):

Is't simple ([ParsleyJS](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html))

> data-parsley-equalto="#anotherfield"

from documentation:

> Validates that the value is identical to another field's value (useful for password confirmation check).

```
<input type="text" data-parsley-equalto="#end-date" id="start-date"/>
<input type="text" data-parsley-equalto="#start-date" id="end-date"/>
```